# Not getting current selected Tab position in android tablayout

Tags: android

I am creating a Tab based application where the user can create tabs by clicking a button and can delete the tabs by clicking another button. I implemented this using Tab layout, Fragments and Viewpager.

I am able to get the current tab position when new tab is created by the function setuptablyout function. But when i clicked another tab ie moving to other tabs I am not able to toast the position.

I found that using  `tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener` I can get the position, while that doesn't work here.

my Activity Code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    TextView textView;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private ImageView add;
    int selectedTabPosition;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.my_viewpager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_tab_layout);
        add= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonAdd1);
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this, viewPager, tabLayout);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        createFirstFragment("POS "+adapter.getCount());
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Pos onTabSelected: "+ tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(adapter.getCount() > 4){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Only 5 Tabs allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("data", "POS "+adapter.getCount());
                    FragmentChild fragmentChild = new FragmentChild();
                    fragmentChild.setArguments(bundle);
                    adapter.addFrag(fragmentChild, "POS "+adapter.getCount());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    if (adapter.getCount() > 0) tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                    Log.e("adapter.getCount()",String.valueOf(adapter.getCount()));
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(adapter.getCount() - 1);
                    setupTabLayout();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void createFirstFragment(String pagename) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("data", pagename);
        FragmentChild fragmentChild = new FragmentChild();
        fragmentChild.setArguments(bundle);
        adapter.addFrag(fragmentChild, pagename);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (adapter.getCount() > 0) tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        Log.e("adapter.getCount()",String.valueOf(adapter.getCount()));
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(adapter.getCount() - 1);
        setupTabLayout();
    }

    public void setupTabLayout() {
        selectedTabPosition = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "selectedTabPosition --> "+selectedTabPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(adapter.getTabView(i));
        }
    }

}
```

ViewPager class:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final ArrayList<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    int selectedTabPosition;
    PreferenceHelper prefs;
    private Map<Integer, String> mFragmentTags;
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private boolean doNotifyDataSetChangedOnce = false;
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, Context context, ViewPager viewPager,
                            TabLayout tabLayout) {
        super(manager);
        this.context = context;
        this.viewPager = viewPager;
        this.tabLayout = tabLayout;
        mFragmentTags = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        prefs = new PreferenceHelper(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (doNotifyDataSetChangedOnce) {
            doNotifyDataSetChangedOnce = false;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    public void removeFrag(int position) {
        removeTab(position);
        Fragment fragment = mFragmentList.get(position);
        mFragmentList.remove(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.remove(position);
        //destroyFragmentView(viewPager, position, fragment);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.e("getCount()", String.valueOf(getCount()));
        if (getCount() > 0)
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabLayout();
    }

    public View getTabView(final int position) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_item, null);
        TextView tabItemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTabItemName);
        ImageView tabItemAvatar =
            (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewTabItemAvatar);
        ImageButton remove = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonRemove);
        if(getCount() == 1){
            remove.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            remove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("Remove", "Remove");
                    if(getCount() != 1){
                        removeFrag(position);
                    }
                    else{
                       // Toast.makeText("Atleast One Tab is requied")
                    }

            }
        });
        tabItemName.setText(mFragmentTitleList.get(position));
        tabItemName.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
        tabItemAvatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.boy);
        return view;
    }
    public void setupTabLayout() {
        selectedTabPosition = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        Toast.makeText(context, "selectedTabPosition --> "+selectedTabPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(getTabView(i));
        }
    }

    public void removeTab(int position) {
        if (tabLayout.getChildCount() > 0 && tabLayout!=null) {
            tabLayout.removeTabAt(position);
            prefs.remove("POS"+position);

        }

    }
    /*@Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        if (mCurrentFragment != object) {
            mCurrentFragment = (Fragment) object;
        }
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
    }*/

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Object object = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        if (object instanceof Fragment) {
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment) object;
            String tag = fragment.getTag();
            mFragmentTags.put(position, tag);
        }
        return object;
    }

    public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String tag = mFragmentTags.get(position);
        if (tag != null) {
            fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

I am getting this weird behaviour that whenever I create new tabs the onTabSelected functions are calling multiple time that even when I create 3rd tab onTabslected toast shows `Pos onTabSelected:` 0,1 and not the just 2nd position which is supposed to be the 2nd position. What can I do to solve this?
My intention is to get some unique tab id so that I can identify each tab separately

Comment: you can use tab.getPosition if you want.

Comment: can you post your `ViewPagerAdapter` adapter class

Comment: @vikassingh updated the `ViewPagerAdapter` class

Comment: @mudit_sen. I tried that. it shows the position, but as I said in the question it shows every tab position when I created each tab. Also how to show `tab.getPosition` when i move or click tabs?

Answer (score 0):

you just create the newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
in your FragmentChild

```
public static FragmentChild  newInstance(int page, String title) {
            FragmentChild  fragmentChild = new FragmentChild ();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("someInt", page);
            args.putString("someTitle", title);
            fragmentChild.setArguments(args);
            return fragmentChild;
        }

        // Store instance variables based on arguments passed
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
            title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
        }
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        TextView tvLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLabel);
        tvLabel.setText(page + " -- " + title);
        return view;
    }
```

And then after in adapter class change this.

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }
```

to

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return FragmentChild.newInstance(position, "Page # 1");

    }
```

I have not tested this code but, I think this code will help you to get your unique tab id..

test this code and let me know if it works

Comment: This only updates FragmentChild right?  FragmentChild is one of example fragment there can be other fragments too. So if i update Adapter class with `FragmentChild.newInstance` this will work only for FragmentChild right?

Comment: Also what is this `fragmentFirst`?

Comment: @KarthikCP right .. as you are adding FragmentChild on button click you will get the same FragmentChild screen itself

Comment: If I add another fragment to tab the how could I change this? I mean I must be able to add any fragment, not just FragmentChild. Then i could not use this `return FragmentChild.newInstance(position, "Page # 1");`

Comment: BTW, when i log the page in FragmentChild, the above behaviour occurs. i.e, On Tab one page is printing 0, when created new Tab pge is printing as 0 and 1 and so on